# how can i make this dialog close when socket is accepted?

Tags: java, swing, sockets, network-programming, jdialog

so i'm developing a game with sockets, at the moment i got this:

```
public void waitconnection() throws IOException {
    try {
         InetAddress address= InetAddress.getLocalHost();

        final JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("IP Hosting " + direccion + " \nPuerto:5000", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, new Object[]{}, null);
        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setTitle("Esperando conexion...");
        dialog.setModal(true);
        dialog.setContentPane(optionPane);
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(pServidor);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    conexion = servidor.accept();

    conexion.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();//acepta el socket y guarda la ip
}
```

i'd like that the dialog window would close upon finding a connection from the client, how could i make that the window closes when reaching a connection and proceed executing the code?

before adding that code i had this:

```
public void waitconnection() throws IOException {
    try {
        InetAddress direccion = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IP Hosting " + direccion + " Puerto:5000", "Esperando conexión", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    conexion = servidor.accept();

    conexion.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
}
```

so when i clicked ok the connection was set and the game would execute in 2 computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server socket code's variables are very tough to read, I have named it in general way in the below code(adjust accordingly). You need to write a method written below as `closeDialog()` [or give a better name]; and call the constructor first, then this method and it'd close the JDialog.

Also, you need to extend the scope of your JDialog upto the class, instead of the method `waitConnection()` by declaring it in the class scope.

> How this code works ?

Socket accept() is a blocking method, which won't execute unless a connection is established; or the socket timeout would occur. You could remove the timeout part, it is just a sample example. So, as soon as a client connects to the Server socket, that would result in execution of the next statement which would dispose the JDialog.

* BTW, I have very less idea of Java Swing, maybe there could be much better ways of closing a JDialog, but I have idea about this one. It should work.

Your code should be something like :-

```
public class Server
{
private ServerSocket serverSocket;

public Server(int port) throws IOException
{
  serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
  // optional timeout part depending on your application.
  serverSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
}

public closeDialog(){
try{
Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
dialog.dispose();
// Rest of your code
}
catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
     {
        System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
     }catch(IOException e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
// Rest of your code
}
```

Comment: thanks for taking your time, i tried what you described above, but it didn't work, i realized that my game crashes until it finds a connection, so it migth be the cause of no response to your method. Anyway i'll leave it like that i figured out an alternative to make it, it's less proffessional but it works.

Comment: @DanielEstebanLadinoTorres - I don't believe the cause of crash to be my method's behaviour, I certainly doubt problems in your Swing code! But, anyways, I am happy that it worked.